# Declaration and declaration with definition. Why is this not allowed?

Tags: c++, overloading, language-lawyer, declaration, definition

I wonder, why it is not allowed to write:

```
struct foo {      
    void bar();                                     // declaration
    void bar(){std::cout << "moo" << std::endl;}    // declaration + definition
};
```

The function is declared twice (I thought this is ok) and defined once. However, my compiler complains about:

```
decldef.cxx:7:10: error: 'void foo::bar()' cannot be overloaded
```

**Why is it not allowed?**

**Why does my compiler (g++ 4.7.2) interpret this as overloading?**

PS: I know how to write it "the correct way", but I just would like to know, why the above is wrong.

Comment: Indeed, but this question does run deeper than that, in my opinion at least. For example, if `struct` was replaced with `namespace` then the code is valid.

Comment: Good question, really. The "+definition" part is actually irrelevant; even a repeated declaration with identical signature is not allowed here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From §9.3

> Except for member function definitions that appear
>   outside of a class definition, and except for explicit specializations of member functions of class templates
>   and member function templates (14.7) appearing outside of the class definition, **a member function shall not
>   be redeclared**.

In addition, in this case the statements may also fall foul of:

> A member function may be defined (8.4) in its class definition, *in which case it is an inline member function*
>   (7.1.2), or it may be defined outside of its class definition if it has *already been declared but not defined
>   in its class definition*.

As the first declaration does not declare the function to be `inline`. The second definition implicitly does.

However, that one on reflection seems less convincing.

Comment: If this is the correct answer, why does `struct foo { void bar(); void bar(); };` fail with the very same error message?

Comment: The second part you quoted is what really answers the question; "_a member function shall not be redeclared_". The inlining difference does not really matter in this context.

Comment: @RichardHodges: You drop the misleading part about inline, and I drop my downvote and answer since you got the correct standard citation. ;-)

Comment: so this is a special rule for member functions, right?

Comment: @tobi303 it seems to be, yes.

Answer (score 5):

> The function is declared twice (I thought this is ok) and defined once.

This is independent of whether or not you define the function the second time around. The point is that you are *declaring* the function twice, and that is *not* OK.

This does not compile either, with the same error message:

```
struct foo {
    void bar();
    void bar();
};
```

You may not re-declare the same function with the same parameter list inside the class definition:

```
'void foo::bar()' cannot be overloaded with 'void foo::bar()'.
```

Comment: Indeed. So is there an explicit statement in the standard somewhere that says _why_ this is not allowed? In my opinion, the compiler's error message is at best misleading, since this is not really an overload...

Comment: @mindriot: Richard Hodges has (edited in) the quote. I don't have a copy of the C++ standard at hand.